# Error in log(obs$y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

I am using the package `growthrates` to analyze growth curves, and I have been getting the weird error that I've never gotten before. When I run the function `all_easylinear()`, I obtain the following error:

```
Error in log(obs$y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

However, the object that is being called (y) is a numeric object. I am completely stumped.

I tried using as.numeric(), but I am still getting the same error.

Example:

```
#example data
odcor_gr <- tibble(
  timeminutes =c(307.428333333333, 327.923333333333, 
348.42, 368.915, 389.411666666667, 409.906666666667, 430.401666666667, 
430.401666666667, 450.896666666667, 471.391666666667, 491.886666666667, 
512.383333333333, 532.878333333333, 553.373333333333, 573.868333333333, 
594.363333333333, 614.858333333333, 635.353333333333, 655.848333333333, 
676.345, 696.84, 717.335), 
  repcor = c(0.31164751485, 0.3728024892, 
0.436049997975, 0.5087474973, 0.58819499865, 0.671152520925, 
0.7614674946, 0.330884997975, 0.361395007425, 0.391364991225, 
0.4193099919, 0.45683998785, 0.484987502025, 0.518939988525, 
0.552150007425, 0.583132508775, 0.614655039825, 0.64367999325, 
0.67689000135, 0.7099650243, 0.75127499865, 0.7855649703), 
  label = c("Y7092_exp1_0", 
"Y7092_exp1_0", "Y7092_exp1_0", "Y7092_exp1_0", "Y7092_exp1_0", 
"Y7092_exp1_0", "Y7092_exp1_0", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", 
"Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", 
"Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", 
"Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", 
"Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", "Y7092_exp1_313.22", 
"Y7092_exp1_313.22"))

fit <- all_easylinear(data=odcor_gr, 
                      grouping="label",
                      time="timeminutes", y="repcor")
```

This produces the following error:

```
Error in log(obs$y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that function doesn't understand tibbles. You can do

```
fit <- all_easylinear(data=as.data.frame(odcor_gr), 
                      grouping="label",
                      time="timeminutes", y="repcor")
```

Specifically the function tries to extract data in columns with code like `odcor_gr[, "timeminutes"]` which for data.frames will return a numeric vector, but for tibbles, this returns another tibble, not a numeric vector.

Comment: The upcoming version of package 'growthrates' will do checks for tibbles (class "tbl_df") internally.